# How do I reflect the colour of a cell in Workbook 1 into Workbook 2?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks where in Workbook 1 I have a macro that updates the interior colour of one cell given the overall status of the project.

Workbook 2 is intended as a summary of all the projects and I need it to reflect the colour of that one cell in Workbook 1.

Im still fairly new to VBA... How would I go about doing that ?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub copyColorOfCell()

    Dim workbook1, workbook2 As Workbook
    Set workbook1 = Workbooks("workbookName1.xlsx")
    Set workbook2 = Workbooks("workbookName2.xlsx")

    Dim worksheet1, worksheet2 As Worksheet
    Set worksheet1 = workbook1.Sheets("worksheetName")
    Set worksheet2 = workbook2.Sheets("worksheetName")

    Dim cell1, cell2 As Range
    Set cell1 = worksheet1.Range("A1")
    Set cell2 = worksheet2.Range("A1")

    cell2.Interior.Color = cell1.Interior.Color

End Sub
```

Replace the workbook and worksheet names (you can also use indexes) and specify the cell you want.

Comment: Note that you have declared `workbook1` and `worksheet1` as `Variant`.  To declare them as `Workbook` and `Worksheet` respectively, you need to use `Dim workbook1 As Workbook, workbook2 As Workbook` and `Dim worksheet1 As Worksheet, worksheet2 As Worksheet`.

Comment: You're correct, I forgot about this. Could you please clarify what are the implications of having them as Variants?

Comment: My main complaint with using `Variants` when they aren't needed is that it sometimes hides problems with the code which makes it hard to debug.  A bit like not having `Option Explicit` - it allows things to happen that you aren't expecting.  Take the following statements as an example: `Dim v, r As Range` `Set r = Range("A1")` `Set v = Range("A1")` `Debug.Print r.Address` `Debug.Print v.Address` - it all works fine - but change `Set v = Range("A1")` to just `v = Range("A1")` and it doesn't crash until you try to access the `.Address` property in the `Debug.Print` line.